# AVD NOT Showing in running android devices

Tags: android, eclipse

[image: Here is photo of AVD is running but not showing in Android running devices]

As show in photo that AVD is running but not showing in Android running devices.
what is the issue?
how can i fix it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

type in command line

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

or goto ddms tab and then on left hand side select drop down and reset adb

see image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16364748/must-do-adb-kill-server-and-start-server-everytime-to-recognize-android-device-i)

command

```
sudo adb kill-server && sudo adb start-server
```

Answer (score 0):

Disconnect your USB attached real device if there is one. It can also be an API missmatch.