# How to restart android adb using terminal on macOS?

Tags: android

I keep having an issue with the Android Studio ADB not recognizing my devices. So far, the only solution I've found is to do a complete reboot of my entire computer, which isn't practical. I'd like to be able to restart the ADB from terminal, because I have seen other posts on here that claim it will fix the issue. However, I can't figure out where to use the commands "adb kill-server", because doing it at the base directory returns a "command not recognized". Can somebody help me figure out how to navigate into Android from terminal and use the command? Or, does anybody have another solution to the original problem of Android Studio not recognizing my devices?

Thanks in advance! Sorry for the wordiness.

Comment: `adb` is under `your-android-sdk-folder/platform-tools/`

Comment: Seems using `sudo` has worked for some, check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16364748/must-do-adb-kill-server-and-start-server-everytime-to-recognize-android-device-i

Comment: sudo didn't work. Thanks, though!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
blackbelt:~ blackbelt$ adb kill-server
blackbelt:~ blackbelt$ adb start-server
```

works on `Linux` as well as on `Mac`. In my machine, `adb` is in [PATH](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/119125/mac-os-x-mavericks-add-to-path)

> "command not recognized". Can somebody help me figure out how to
>   navigate into Android from terminal and use the command? Or, does
>   anybody have another solution to the original problem of Android
>   Studio not recognizing my devices?

In your case `adb` is not declared in `PATH`. You can either export the `PATH`, or specify the full qualified path to `adb` in the command line. E.g.

```
 blackbelt:~ blackbelt$ /path/to/platform-tools/adb kill-server
 blackbelt:~ blackbelt$ /path/to/platform-tools/adb start-server
```

or

```
 blackbelt:~ blackbelt$ ./adb kill-server
 blackbelt:~ blackbelt$ ./adb start-server
```

if you are inside `platform-tools`

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I tried using the full path to the adb file like you said, but that gives me a "No such file or directory" error. I also tried navigating into the platform-tools directory, then using "adb kill-server" but it still gives me a "command not recognized" error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try `./adb kill-server` under the platform-tools directory

Comment: Aha, that was it. Thanks Blackbelt and Carlo!

Answer (score 4):

Well instead of doing it through command line, if you find that hard you can also do the same from android studio. 
Go to tools -> Android -> Android device monitor . Then it will open the separate window where you can see all the devices or emulator attached to the process. On the left hand side below the Devices tab there will be and menu bar, you need to click on the drop down arrow which will give you the option to reset the adb. Here is the image for reference [image]

If you are using windows try to update the device driver for your device make sure the adb is correctly installed. When you connect your device to system see if it is allowed to be used at the system.

Comment: This returns a weird error for me (Adb connection Error:EOF) and doesn't work. Not sure why

Comment: Interesting, never happened to me anyways the error message that you got generally means the connection to dab has been lost. Adb is the process which remains live for longer period so the studio showed you warning about its lost state. I think if you allow it some time it should get started automatically after 11-12 attempt by the studio itself.

Answer (score 2):

if `adb kill-server` not responding. Find the process id (`PID`) by typing `top` in terminal and finding PID next to `adb`. Then type `kill <PID>`

For example, for me PID for adb was 70163. Then i typed `kill 70163`

Answer (score 0):

Simply stop `adb`:

```
adb kill-server
```

Then you can start it again any time:

```
adb start-server
```